# mySQLi database error which i don't know , First this query run fine but now not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

i have run this query before and inserted the record in database but now that's not working fine. i searched for solutions,  my database size is 1.6MB and also i increase the default size of xampp in php.ini from 2Mb to 20 MB and refresh the apache and mysql server. but no solution working

here is my code

```
        function saveProduct($myproductName , $myproductType , $mymyimage , $techInfo , $charactristics , $specifications , $properties)
        {
            $mycon = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connected to database");
            mysqli_select_db($mycon, "zic_app");
            $qry="INSERT INTO zic_catalog (productName, productImage, productType, vhviTech, generalCharactristics, specifications, properties) VALUES ('".$myproductName."' , '".$mymyimage."' , '".$myproductType."' , '".$techInfo."'  , '".$charactristics."' , '".$specifications."' , '".$properties."')";
            ?>
            <br /><br /><br />
            <?php
            $result=mysqli_query($mycon, $qry);
            if($result)
            {

                echo( "publish successfully...");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Product Not published: " . mysqli_error($mycon);
            }
        }
```

and this is the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's manual Transmission fluid specification and other major car manufacturers wher' at line 1

Comment: `echo $qry;` print your query and run in phpmyadmin check is it working or not

Comment: Read what the error is. Then post here the code that correspond to it. The error has something to do with the `WHERE` clause but the query you posted doesn't have one.

Comment: How many times are you running this function, this might be the case that time out error is occuring

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: i am calling this function once the solution of @RamRaider has resolved my problem and thanks for helping me

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If there is an `apostrophe` in the data it will break the sql - use escaped double quotes in the sql instead or convert the data using `htmlentities`

```
$qry="INSERT INTO zic_catalog (productName, productImage, productType, vhviTech, generalCharactristics, specifications, properties) 
VALUES 
(\"{$myproductName}\" , \"{$mymyimage}\" , \"{$myproductType}\" , \"{$techInfo}\"  , \"{$charactristics}\" , \"{$specifications}\" , \"{$properties}\")";
```

Comment: No problem - glad it helped. Shame a correct solution ( not necessarily the best solution ) was given a downvote though

Comment: This takes a problem and turns it into a mess. The correct answer here is to switch to prepared statements. This has *zero* escaping, it just switches the conflict from single quotes to doubles.

Comment: hence `not the best solution`

Comment: The best solution is one that isn't a duct-tape fix on a problem that could blow up in a huge way. Your idea of using `htmlentities` is so shockingly bad I wish I could downvote this twice. Are you serious?

Comment: sorry for downvote i am new here and no idea about downvote or upvote     that is mistakenly happen